# Access GPX files of other apps from my app, in android

Tags: android, android-studio, gpx

I am beginner in developing android app.
I am building an app which needs to read the GPX files generated by apps such as Runkeeper or Strava. First of all, is it possible to do so? If so what are the technologies available to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the other app store the GPX file. If it's in the external storage, just add READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission then read it. 
If it's in the /data/data/xxx.xxx.xxx/ folder, then you have to get the root privilege.